# Do we need commit() database connection after query was executed and no changes were made (auto commit is "off")?

Tags: java, sql, database, commit, hsqldb

Simple question, but.. just want to be sure. If database connection is set to `conn.setAutoCommit(false);`, after `st.executeQuery(...);` - do we need to `conn.commit();`? Of course, if some changes were made like `st.execute(...);` - `conn.commit();` is needed. I'm using `HSQLDB`.

Answer (score 5):

In addition to committing updates, `commit` also releases locks, so it is useful to call `commit` after executing queries even if no updates were made (though this may be true only for specific databases, and you didn't specify which DB you are using).

Comment: Very interesting to know that it depends on DB.. Using `HSQLDB`.

Comment: @ErnestasGruodis I only added the comment about specific DBs since I can't be sure my answer is correct for all DBs. I don't know anything about HSQLDB. The Javadoc of Connection.commit says that it releases any database locks currently held by this Connection, but perhaps some DBs don't hold any locks if you only execute queries and no updates.